# How to stream mp3 file directly from Dropbox using dropbox api in android

Tags: java, android

I want to stream mp3 file directly from dropbox to my android app. I am using Dropbox Core Api and MediaPlayer to play audio. But  MediaPlayer accept URL or File. From Dropbox code api I am getting InputStream and Shared URL. I tried with share URL but is not working. Shared url is look like this : https://db.tt/117aYGdu and 2nd option is InputStream in Dropbox there is a method mApi.getFileStream(path, rev) that return inputstrem of file. But how to use it with android MediaPlayer.

Comment: You must be using the `/shares` api, why aren't you using `/media`?

Answer (score 2):

After searching a lot in Drivebox Core API Reference I fond one method call media

```
DropboxLink dropboxMediaLink = mApi.media(path, false);
```

Here path is your entry.path and ssl here i set false.